# Let $H=\{I, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $S_4$, so that $S_4/H$ has order six.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $H=\{I, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. Show that $H$ is a normal
>   subgroup of $S_4$, so that $S_4/H$ has order six.

I don't see any quick way of showing that it's normal. I haven't actually attempted the last part, but the wording of the question "so that" implies that it obviously follows, but it doesn't follow immediately for me.

Thank you

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Showing that $H$ is a subgroup? That it's normal? That the quotient has order $6$? Please help us help you.

Comment: Sorry, I was just getting really stressed with this question because I feel that it should be very easy and on another day I wouldn't have an issue with it. I don't see any quick way of showing that it's normal. I haven't actually attempted the last part, but the wording of the question "so that" implies that it obviously follows, but it doesn't follow immediately for me. Thank you

Comment: Well, $\left\lvert G/H\right\rvert =\dfrac{\lvert G\rvert}{\lvert H\rvert}$ always holds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $V = \{\mathrm{id}, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(4)$...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736610/let-h-i-1234-1324-1423-show-that-h-is-a-normal-subgroup).

Answer (score 3):

Conjugating an element of $S_n$ with another element of $S_n$ produces an element of same cycle type as the original. As the subgroup $H$ contains *all* elements of cycle type $(a\,b)(c\,d)$, it must be normal.

Answer (score 1):

Since $4$-cycles and transpositions are odd permutations, $H$ is the only subgroup with $4$ elements of $A_4$.

Hence, $H$ is a characteristic subgroup of $A_4$, which is a normal subgroup of $S_4$.

Characteristic subgroups of normal subgroups are normal.